# How to display virtual keyboard when a physical keyboard is connected

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Is there a way to programmatically force the virtual keyboard to appear when there is a bluetooth keyboard connected to the iPad?

I have a bluetooth barcode scanner connected to the iPad, which acts as HID (keyboard). The problem is, the virtual keyboard stays hidden in my app. Is there any way I could force the virtual keyboard to show without using any unofficial SDK calls?

Answer (score 1):

Darn I was hoping someone would be able to answer this question! Goran have you been able to find anything since July?

I have one idea, although I'm not sure whether it works or not... Apparently the Apple bluetooth keyboard has a shortcut that opens the virtual keyboard. If, using javascript, you can send this command to the iPad, the virtual keyboard will open?? Is this possible?